# hot to filter a column of type array - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, filter

I have a column price type array in database

```
'price' => [
            'basic' => 5,
            'standard' =>15,
            'premium' => 20
        ],
```

How can I filter by price using a query

```
whereBetween('price',[1,19])
```

I want to check all packages

Comment: Assuming your array is backed by a JSON column then take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses